# Which PayloadType used for the Apps while install profile using MDM on ios BYOD?

Tags: ios, profile, mdm

I have enrol profile with MDM in BYOD (Buy Your Own devices) and i want to install profile APPs as screentime ios app use to hide all application except it self app. I am unable to found to payload type for the profile. Here i attached screen shot with highlighted what i want.[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf#page52

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks for the document, but i am unable to find any payloadType for the APPS with its keys.

Comment: Page 53, which I linked to, contains the install app command details.  App details are not included in the profile.  Once an MDM installs an app then it is associated with the profile and shows in the screen you have shown.